# CSS: How to adjust two divs align at bottom which use float property and auto width and height

Tags: html, css, adjustment

I'm working with 5 divs:

- Main Div (works as wrapper, width and height set to `auto`)
- sub div (contains two divs, red and blue, `width:75%` and `height:auto`)

  - red div (`height:90%` `width:auto)`
  - green div (`height:10%` `width:auto`)
- blue div (`width:25%` `height:auto`)

as shown below:

[image]

with current width and height settings divs are proportionally responsive to each other.

but problem is if I set `height:89%`  `bottom-margin:1%` of red div, then they do not produce the same output, sub div which contains red and green, get more height if veiwport is small and it becomes shorter than blue div if viewport is large screen.

I want to adjust it in such a manner that green div remains adjusted accordingly with blue div at bottom all the time, no matters what device i'm using.

Now unfortunately my `code` doesn't seem to work with `fiddle` and neither does `snippet` work, but it works on my browser and so does on [liveweave.com](http://liveweave.com).

here is working example on [liveweave.com](http://liveweave.com/MMgPnf)

here is my complete code:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="sub">
      <div class="red"></div>
      <div class="green"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.main{
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
 }
.sub{
  width: 75%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
.red{
  width: 100%;
  height: 85%;
  background-color: red;
}
.green{
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: green;
}
.blue{
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Flexbox` to create this layout. Flexbox will make flex-items same height by default so if you increase height of blue div, it will increase height of `sub` div also.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
}
.sub {
  flex: 3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.red {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
}
.green {
  background: green;
  flex: 0 0 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: well that's what exactly i was looking for. thnx buddy, i'm not much into flex layout btw, so can you please explain how would this work `flex: 0 0 10%` , i understand `10%` represents the height of green div, but what's the function of `0 0` in it? and how does flex order works?

Comment: If the `flex-direction` on parent is set to `column` then flex property will define height of flex-item, and `flex: 0 0 10%` is shorthand of `flex-grow: 0`, `flex-shrink: 0` and `flex-basis: 10%`, so basically it will set fixed height of element to 10%